# Asset shadow not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi this is my first time importing assets in unity and I encountered a problem in asset. The problem is some shadow is not showing. Below is the asset https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/sports/game/billiard-pool-table-4a97b4bb488c81810c3f044c2b44473a?fbclid=IwAR1pJpEw3Jw-GDuioTufks2GS3_krtRyis33R_YoPMm4tW2lMODTJjRUlXM

Below is the published version

[image]

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: You can have multiple reasons for that, the first I can think of is that the light source is probably from straight above the table (so you can't see the shadow)
Look at this post and try to see if your issue isn't from one of those reasons : https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/207927086-Shadows-My-Shadows-do-not-show-in-the-Editor-view-or-Game-View-

Comment: @Kyysel Thanks I have solved this problem cause the directional light is pointing sideways